# on image hover adds a spacing to the left

Tags: html, css, hover, spacing

[My Site - Product Grid](http://t16850-s25933.sandbox.mozu.com/exam-vouchers/c/19)

When you hover over either of the product images on this page, there is a 2px horizontal line that appears to the left.  I tried setting my padding, margin, no-wrap, I just can't figure it out.  Thanks for looking and any advice.

I know I can cheat it by adding:

```
.mz-productlisting-image img {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

But I don't want to if I don't have to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the text-decoration:underline; of the anchor tag.

Simply add to

```
.mz-productlist-tiled a:focus,
.mz-productlist-tiled a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Hope it helps :)